# which is the recomended way to set width to table columns?

Tags: html

i use to be in this scenario i mean trying to set table columns width, i want to know which one is the best way

right now i am using this way, but most of the time i am just guessing, setting th width attribute to 1 to pull column to left

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th width="1">Column1<th>
        <th width="1">Column2<th>
        <th>Column3<th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>some content<td>
            <td>more content<td>
            <td>even more content<td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

thanks

Comment: use css `table thead th {width: 10px;} `

Answer (score 0):

Assign one ID/Class for table. Using as a reference, assign your table cell and table header styles. If you want to aligning left your table cell, no need to keep width 1 pixel. You can add text-align property for that cell.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="MyCustomTable">
<thead>
    <th>Column1<th>
    <th>Column2<th>
    <th>Column3<th>
    <th>Column4<th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>some content<td>
        <td>more content<td>
        <td>even more content<td>
        <td>even more content new<td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#MyCustomTable
{
 width:100%;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
}
 #MyCustomTable th
{
 text-align:center;
 width:25%; 
 background-color:#d8d8d8;
 font-weight:700;
 }
#MyCustomTable td
{
 text-align:left;
 width:25%; 
}
```